# JMeter load client-side certificate

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ssl-certificate, jks, p12

I try to add a `p12` file to `JMeter 3.3` configuration to reach a site.
I added following lines to `system.properties` file:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\certs\mycert.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword
```

After that I restarted `JMeter`, but got the same error, `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`. I converted `p12` file with keytool to `jks` and added the following lines to same file by replacing previous ones.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\certs\mycert.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypassword
```

Error message is the same in this case too:

> Response code: Non HTTP response code:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException Response message: Non HTTP
>   response message: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I use HTTP Client 4 as implementation for HTTP Samplers. When I import same certificate to browser, it is working correctly.

I tried to follow this tutorial too: [How to configure JMeter to use client side SSL](https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/docs/how-to-test-your-apis/how-to-configure-jmeter-to-use-client-side-ssl/)

Comment: Did you check tutorial https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/docs/how-to-test-your-apis/how-to-configure-jmeter-to-use-client-side-ssl/?

Comment: @user7294900 : Yes, sure, but it doesn't helped.

Comment: set `javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose` and see what it says about actual reason for handshake to fail

Comment: @KirilS. : Is it possible to import it on project-level? So it could be saved and shipped with `.jmx` file.

Comment: with jmx file - no. You can change them on the fly (for example by providing command line with cert location, or using system.properties), but certificates really have nothing to do with JMeter, they are set on JVM level (see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqw/index.html), so accepting or not recognizing it still depends on Java installed on each machine. So it's usually better to consider them to be part of system requirements for JMeter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Options** -> **SSL Manager** option, where you can select your `.p12` file to be used in current Test plan.

Comment: I am looking for some solution, which could be saved and shipped with project.